# small caps for author names in chapter bibliographies with biber works only in first chapter

Tags: biblatex, small-caps, chapterbib

the following minimal example (using sections instead of chapters solely to limit the number of empty pages) shows the problem:

```
    \begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
  @BOOK{Ogg-05,
    title        = {A Practical Guide to Quality Management in Clinical Trial Research},
    author       = {Ogg, G.D.},
    publisher    = {Informa HealthCare },
    year         = {2005},
    address      = {Boca Raton (FL, USA)},
    isbn         = {9780849397226},
  }
  @PATENT{Okh-86,
    AUTHOR       = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Охонин, В.А.}} [Okhonin, V.A.]}},
    holder       = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Институт Биофизики со ан СССР}} [Biophysical Institute of the SSSR]}},
    sortname     = {Okhonin, V.A.},
    shortauthor  = {Okhonin},
    TITLE        = {{{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Способ исследования микроструктуры образца}}} [Method of investigating specimen microstructure]},
    sorttitle    = {Method of investigating specimen microstructure},
    year         = {1986},
    month        = {4},
    number       = {SU 1374922},
    url          = {https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=SU29122026},
    langid       = {russian},
    abstract     = {Sovietisches Patent, daß die Grundlagen der STED Mikroskopie beschreibt },
  }

  @ARTICLE{Orn-62,
    title        = {Disk electrophoresis: {I}. {B}ackground and theory},
    author       = {Ornstein, L.},
    journal      = {Ann. N. Y. Acad. Sci.},
    year         = {1962},
    pages        = {321-351},
    volume       = {121},
    number       = {2},
    abstract     = {Einführung und theoretische Behandlung der diskontinuierlichen Elektrophorese},
    doi          = {10.1111/j.1749-6632.1964.tb14207.x},
  }
\end{filecontents}

% -*- TeX:UK -*-
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX spellcheck = en_GB
% !BIB program = biber
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kpfonts-otf, polyglossia}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=UTF8,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setotherlanguage[babelshorthands=true,numerals=arabic]{russian}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{FreeSerif}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}       %

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\title{Test}
\author{Tester}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First section}
\begin{refsection}

The quick brown fox\parencite{Ogg-05,Okh-86,Orn-62} jumps over the lazy dog.

\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\end{refsection}

\section{Second section}
\begin{refsection}

The quick brown fox\parencite{Orn-62} jumps over the lazy dog.

\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

The author names of the first section are in small caps, as intended. However, in the second section, it is in normal font, and I do not understand why. It seems to have to do with the Russian source, if this is removed, small caps are used in the second section as well. But if that causes the problem, why is the third reference in the first section not affected? And how do I get around the problem?
[image: LaTeX output (MikTeX)]

Comment: looks ok in a current texlive see https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RtcW.png. (But there are a few /.notdef glyphs, so you should reconsider your font choice).

Comment: I tried with TeX Live 2020, 2021 and 2023; in all cases I get no issue. By the way, you're forgetting `\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}`, because `polyglossia` will not get this from the `british` document class option (and this is the cause for the missing characters).

Comment: Hm, I am using MikTeX, could make a difference? Anyway, I added an image of the output. Thanks for the hint with \setmainlanguage

Comment: Works fine (well, OK-ish, like Ulrike I get a couple of missing characters, but the small caps are there) for me on a more-or-less-recently updated MikTeX (compiled with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX just to be sure). Can you minimise your code even further and share the `.log` file?

Comment: How would I do that? I do not find any options to make files available.

Comment: Usually `.log` files are too long to be included here (that's why I suggested making the example even smaller: remove as much as you can while still retaining the issue, do you need all example entries?). You will have to upload them to a third-party website. Use a text-sharing service such as https://pastebin.com/, https://paste.ec/, https://gist.github.com/, https://gitlab.com/explore/snippets, ... (please don't use a service that requires us to download the file before viewing)

Comment: I put it under https://pastebin.com/W7676Sbr, valid for 1 week. Looking at the output more closely, it appears that more is wrong than just failing to use \textsc, the text runs narrower, too.

Comment: Hmmm. One of the differences between our two `.log` files is that your document ends up loading `british`, while mine doesn't. As egreg says this is one of the reasons why we get some missing characters. If I say `\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}` before `\setotherlanguage[babelshorthands=true,numerals=arabic]{russian}` I no longer have missing characters *and* the small caps are still fine. In any case, you should definitely add the `\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}` line.

Comment: The other difference is that in the `Font family 'FreeSerif(0)' created for font 'FreeSerif'` block I have `<->"FreeSerif/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"` after `- 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.:`, but you have nothing there. Consequently you later get ```Font shape `TU/FreeSerif(0)/m/sc' undefined```, which I don't get. It appears that your `FreeSerif` is different from mine or broken. Try reinstalling the font.